# Imprimir lista de objetos

Tags: python

Estoy creando una lista de objetos y quiero que al imprimir la lista me regrese lo que le asigno a la funcion `__str__`, mi codigo es el siguiente

```
import numpy as np

class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, name, cal):
        self.name = name
        self.cal = cal

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.cal + other.cal

    def __str__(self):
        return f"El alumno {self.name} tiene una calificacion de: {self.cal}"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cal < other.cal

alumnos = []
for i in range(10):
    cal = np.random.randint(1,11)
    alumno = Alumno("nombre", cal)
    alumnos.append(alumno)

#Lo que quiero hacer
print(sorted(alumnos))

#Lo que tengo que hacer
alumnos = sorted(alumnos)
for alumno in alumnos:
    print(alumno)
```

Lo que quiero es que me imprima algo asi

> El alumno nombre tiene una calificacion de: x

Para cada alumno, pero me imprime lo siguiente

> <**main**.Alumno object at 0x0000016071CD2CF8>

He intentado resolverlo con `__next__` e `__iter__` pero no he logrado resolverlo. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python tiene dos formas de convertir un objeto cualquiera en una cadena de caracteres, de cara a volcarlo por pantalla.

Una es:

```
str(objeto)
```

y ésta es la que se usa si intentas `print(objeto)`, e internamente lo que hace es llamar a `objeto.__str__()` para que haga esa conversión. Esa es la función que tú has definido y por eso `print(objeto)` te sale bien.

La otra es:

```
repr(objeto)
```

y ésta se llama cuando en el intérprete interactivo debe mostrar el resultado de evaluar la expresión `objeto`, es decir, en:

```
$ python
>>> objeto
<main.Alumno object at 0x0000016071CD2CF8>
```

y también cuando ese objeto está dentro de otra estructura (una lista, un diccionario, una tupla) y quieres convertir la estructura en cadena. Es decir, cuando tu programa hace algo como:

```
print([objeto1, objeto2])
```

En este caso, `print()` invocará a `list.__str__()` para que la lista devuelva su representación como string, pero esa función lo que hace es invocar en bucle a `repr()` para cada elemento de la lista.  A su vez `repr(objeto)` invoca a `objeto.__repr__()`. Ya que esta no la tienes definida, usa la implementación por defecto que es la que muestra ese "feo" resultado.

Si defines sólo `__repr__()` (y no `__str__()`) tienes ambas cosas, ya que `str(objeto)` intenta invocar `objeto.__str__()`, pero si no lo encuentra, invoca entonces `objeto.__repr__()`. De este modo definiendo sólo una, de algún modo "tienes las dos". Pero si prefieres también puedes definir ambas de diferente forma, y así obtener diferente representación según la circunstancia.

Una última observación. Por convenio se espera que `__repr__()` devuelva una cadena que "parezca código python". Es decir, que pudiera copiarse y pegarse en un programa y que funcionaría. Siguiendo este convenio `repr(alumno)` debería devolver la cadena `"Alumno('nombre', 5)"` por ejemplo. En tu caso estarías violando esta convención, pero tampoco pasa nada, es factible.

Lo que devuelva `__str__()` en cambio es completamente libre.

Answer (score 3):

En vez de sobrecargar `__str__` utiliza `__repr__`.

Comment: funciono perfecto, muchas gracias